# create folder from part filename with {*.*}

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, directory

i have a folder with over 1000 images. all images names are like this:
{number}{number}{date}{name}{name2}1.jpg

i need a batch (.bat file) script that will create a folder with the image {name}, subfolder with {date} and move the files.

I have tried with `set "folder1=!filename1:~20,25!"` but my first {number} and second {number} can have 3-4 character and i cannot create a rule.

can you help me pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for %%z in ("c:\folder\*.jpg") do for /f "tokens=3,4 delims={}" %%a in ("%%~nz") do (
    mkdir "c:\target\%%b\%%a" >nul 2>nul
    echo move "%%~fz" "c:\target\%%b\%%a"
)
```

If the output to console is correct, remove the `echo` before the `move` command.

Comment: thank you, it's great. you are my saviour for today.

Comment: @rozatrra - if the answer completely solved your problem, then you should probably accept it by clicking on the check mark in the upper left corner. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and awards the answer poster 15 points. Only one answer per question can be accepted. Once you reach 15 rep points you will have the ability to up vote any answer you find useful, including answers to other people's questions.